# Filtering Geoserver WFS by using a reverse bounding box

Tags: qgis, postgis, geoserver

So I have a WFS being served through Geoserver that links to a Postgis table.

It's a very large table so up until now I've been checking the box that says "Only request features overlapping current view extent" but the problem is that the data sometimes keeps going on a loop and it's impossible to work in some areas

The workaround I thought about was to use a bounding box for the area with very high frequency of events and another for everything outside of it. How to do this?

Comment: Not sure how to do it with QGIS, but I suppose you would like to use the WFS Disjoint filter http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function.html which is the opposite to Intersects.